# Python flask get request in Ajax

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, ajax

I'm executin this code in Flask python to request. an API with those parameters :

```
payload = {'key':'pass', 'schema':'sch', 'table':'tab','where_clause':'0', 'liste_fields':'*}
r = requests.get('https://api.com/', params=payload, verify=False)
```

How can I execute the same get url in Ajax ?

```
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://api.com/",
            type: "POST",
            data: ?,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {
                alert(result);
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {

            }
```

Comment: I don't follow what this has to do with Flask?

Comment: Did you try this? `data: JSON.stringify({ "key": "pass", "schema": "sch", ... });` also there's a problem in your code `params=playload` means you're sending a get request, but your js code is sending a post request.

Comment: Try this too : `type: "get", data: { "key": "pass", "schema": "sch", ... }` to make a get request.